# scroll view disable only in portrait mode in android

Tags: android

i had a scrollview in my xml but the scroll view should only work in landscape mode of the phone but not in portrait mode of phone.can this is possible and if possible so i should go with the xml file or through programmatically.if code require please ask me.Thanks

here is the xml file(portrait mode):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1e90ff"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#a9a9a9"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_tauky_button_img" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/explore_button_img"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/create_tauky_button_img" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/my_blauky_button_img" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_button_img" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your simplest solution is to check:

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

in `onCreate()` and disable the `ScrollView` if the orientation is `portrait`. See reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

It works because by default `Activities` are restarted on configuration changes (including change in orientation), so you don't have to listen for this event.

Simply modify your `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

    // disable ScrollView in portrait mode
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview1);
        scrollView.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

where `activity_layout` is your layout file name (without `.xml` extension). That's it!

Comment: what is the method to disable it

Answer (score 0):

create two different xml layouts.one for portrait mode(put it in your default "layout" folder)and one for landscape(create a "layout-land" folder and put it there), and add a scroll view only in the second one.

Comment: i want scroll view  effect only in landscape mode

Comment: exactly.if you put a scroll view only in the xml from the 'layout-land ' folder,you will have a scroll effect only in landscape mode.You can create different layouts for landscape mode and place the in 'layout-land' folder(you need to create it) and android will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  scrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :)

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation) {
        case Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT:
            ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollview1);
            scrollView.setEnabled(false);
            break;

}
```

Comment: android:enabled is not there in scrollview tag

Comment: I realized it. Wrong move! Changing it! :)